# How many different necklaces can be formed with $6$ white and $5$ red beads?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many different necklaces can be formed with $6$ white and $5$ red beads?

Since total number of beads is $11$ according to me it should be $\dfrac{11!}{6!5!}$ but correct answer is $21$. How does that come?

Comment: since the necklace is "circular" there are many repeated similar combinations in $\dfrac{11!}{6!5!}$

Comment: By my reckoning, the answer is $26$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  I get $26$ for a [bracelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)), which is invariant under both rotation and reflection.  However, by convention, necklaces are only invariant under rotation.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Then in that case, the answer is 42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we are calculating the circular arrangements then we do $(n-1)!$. This is the case when clockwise and anti clockwise  are different.

And when clockwise and anti clockwise are same, then we use $(n-1)!/2$.

So according to the Que we apply 2 formula
$$(11-1)!/2×5!×6!
=21.$$

Comment: Doesn't add anything new to the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

First consider $$\dfrac{11!}{5!6!}$$ as you have done. Now since the necklace is "circular" you must divide by the number of beads to remove the repeated arrangements, that is:$$\dfrac{11!}{5!6!11}$$

Also, the necklace can be flipped over, thus twice as many combinations had been counted so far, so you must divide by 2. That is:$$\dfrac{11!}{5!\cdot6!\cdot11 \cdot 2}=21$$

Comment: But some necklaces are preserved by the "flipping over" operation.

Comment: Are you referring to the cases where the beads are "symmetrical"...such as: rrwwwrr ?

Comment: Exactly, one needs some (slightly) non-trivial application of Burnside's lemma.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics), the convention in combinatorics is that a "necklace" cannot be flipped over.  If it can be flipped, it is called a "bracelet".