# How many necklaces with given certain colored beads

Tags: combinatorics, necklace-and-bracelets

I am interested to know if there's a way to calculate the number of (rotation agnostic) necklaces that can be produced from different colored beads, each color with its own quantity.

For instance, if I have a 3 red beads, 2 green beads and 1 blue bead, I can produce 10 distinct necklaces (see attached image).

However, other than constructing all the necklaces and counting them (which is what I did), how can I arrive at the number of distinct necklaces that can be produced with the given beads?

Note, I am looking for a general solution, where the number of colors, and the quantity of beads in each color can be given freely.

Can you help?

[image]

**EDIT:**

It appears that I figured out a formula that works for the majority of cases. It fails however when the quantity of all the beads has a common denominator.

[image: \frac{(a_1+a_2+\ \cdots\ +\ a_n-1)!}{a_1!\ \bullet\ a_2!\ \bullet\cdots\ \bulleta_n!}]

So this works, unless I have 2 of each bead, or 3 of each bead. Or 2 and 4 of each bead, etc.

Can't figure out how to solve for that case though..

Comment: In this case:  place the blue one (that fixes the rotation).  You now have $5$ slots.  Place the red ones.  $\binom 53=10$.

Comment: Clever way to think of this particular case, but the specific case was brought to illustrate the problem. I'm looking for a general solution.

Comment: But in general there is work involved.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187062/number-of-different-necklaces-with-2-black-and-6-white-beads) for a discussion of one example, and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) for a variant.

Comment: Side note:  I don't see colors very well, but it seems to me that one of your pictures (second from the left in the bottom row) has only one green bead.

Comment: You're correct, I fixed the image :)

Comment: Phew.  I  only gave myself a $50-50$ shot at being right about that.  Red-green can be just a question of mood.

Comment: @lulu, so do you believe there is no formula that can be applied for a general case? say: 7 blue, 5 green, 3 red, 2 purple? 
It's 2,882880. I produced all necklaces via computer, and counted them. But these kinds of calculations are very expensive. I'm looking for a way to come up with the number without producing the actual necklaces..

Comment: Oh, there is, sort of...the links I proposed reference the Poyla Enumeration Theorem, which is at the heart of problems like this.  There is a generating function approach you can use, which is sketched [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186157/counting-necklaces-with-a-fixed-number-of-each-bead).

Comment: [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) and [Polya's enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) can be applied to this type of problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that before. I am not a mathematician, and I'm having a hard time interpreting the mathematical notation and adapt it to my problem. Would either of you be willing to help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

To use the Pólya enumeration theorem we first need to weight the beads so that the given bead distribution is the *only* way to make the combined weight from an arbitrary selection of however many beads are in the necklace. One way that works here is to have weight-$0$ red, weight-$2$ green and weight-$3$ blue beads, since $7$ can only be written as $3+2+2+0+0+0$. This leads to a certain generating function
$$f(t)=1+t^2+t^3$$
We now need the cycle index polynomial, which here is
$$Z_{C_6}(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_6)=\frac16(t_1^6+2t_6+2t_3^2+t_2^3)$$
Then the desired count is the $t^w$ coefficient of $Z$ with the $t_i$ argument assuming a value of $f(t^i)$, where $w$ is the total weight of beads under the given weighting. Here we get
$$[t^7]Z(f(t),f(t^2),f(t^3),f(t^6))=10$$
as expected.

---

The contrived weights above were to keep things simple for a first explanation – $f$ does not have to be single-variable, and the colours need not be numbers; they can be vectors of integers. We can assign red, green and blue weights of $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$ respectively, then clearly the desired distribution of weights corresponds only to $(2,1)$ and
$$f(t,u)=1+t+u$$
The $f$ put in the $t_i$ argument of $Z$ now has all its arguments to the $i$th power, and in this case we have the answer as
$$[t^2u]Z(f(t,u),f(t^2,u^2),f(t^3,u^3),f(t^6,u^6))=10$$